# How to Crop a image via finger touch in Android App?

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-paint, android-crop

[ORIGINAL]

I am working on a project in which i need to create summary of book (combination of images). Summary includes parts of image masked by finger. I found an example for android i.e [fingercrop-image-tutorial](http://codesfor.in/android-fingercrop-image-tutorial) but it is not what i want. What i want is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47413816/9577954) for an Ionic app.

Can someone tell me how to do this in android?

[NOTE : before down-voting, please check provided link of ionic app and press "run code snippet" button below code to see what i want]

[EDITED]

tried something and now getting [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBKDl.gif). Can someone help me to crop whole marked part.I am using same code as [fingercrop-image-tutorial](http://codesfor.in/android-fingercrop-image-tutorial). changes made in `initcanvas()` method are :

1. paint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
2. paint.setStrokeWidth(60);
3. paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DARKEN));

`crop()` function is same.

Comment: https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper if you are ok with libraries

Comment: @AswinPAshok I wan to crop like https://stackoverflow.com/a/47413816/9577954. check "Run code snippet" below code.

Comment: @KushVatsa Have you check "Run code snippet" below code of Ionic app?

Comment: I found Cropper.js to be better than any of the plugins for Ionic. Here's the demo:

https://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropperjs/

Comment: @TroyMyers I dont want simple rectangle cropper.please check provided link of ionic app and run snippet to see what i want.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50384867/free-crop-the-image-android. This is a question (Check out the attached images). There are some minor issue to be fixed.

Comment: @AswinPAshok The android example i mentioned above does the same thing and i have already implemented it in my app. but i dont want image **between** drawn path.