# Free crop the image android

Tags: android, imagefilter

I want to crop the image with multiple paths like the below image:

[image: Screenshot].

So far, what I have implemented saves all drawn paths into an `ArrayList`, then I retrieve those cropped paths in another activity.

However, every path is adding the first drawn point.

Here's my code:

```java
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        points.clear();
        points2 = new ArrayList<Point>();
    }

    Point point = new Point();
    point.x = (int) event.getX();
    point.y = (int) event.getY();

    zoomPos.x = event.getX();
    zoomPos.y = event.getY();

    if (flgPathDraw) {
        zooming = true;
        if (bfirstpoint) {
            if (comparepoint(mfirstpoint, point)) {
                points.add(mfirstpoint);
                points2.add(mfirstpoint);
            } else {
                points.add(point);
                points2.add(point);
            }
        } else {
            points.add(point);
            points2.add(point);
        }
        if (!(bfirstpoint)) {
            mfirstpoint = point;
            bfirstpoint = true;
        }
    }

    invalidate();
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        mlastpoint = point;
        if (flgPathDraw) {
            if (points.size() > 12) {
                if (!comparepoint(mfirstpoint, mlastpoint)) {
                    zooming = false; 
                    points2.add(mfirstpoint);

                    addpaths.add(path);

                    invalidate();
                }
            }
        }

        if (points2!=null&&!(points2.isEmpty())) {
            pointlists.add(points2);
        }

    }

    return true;
}

//Croping code for drawn paths.

for (int j=0;j<CutPhotoView.pointlists.size();j++) {
    for (int i = 0; i <CutPhotoView.pointlists.get(j).size(); i++) {
        path.lineTo(CutPhotoView.pointlists.get(j).get(i).x, 
                    CutPhotoView.pointlists.get(j).get(i).y);
    }
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
}
```

[image: drawn paths]

[image: got the output]

Answer (score 0):

By modifying [this](http://codesfor.in/android-fingercrop-image-tutorial) example you can do it.

1. create a `List<Bitmap>`.
2. call `save();` at end of crop method.
3. in save method, generate bitmap of im_crop_image_view and add it to list.
4. after all crops, pass list to second activity.
5. in second activity, use FrameLayout and add dynamic imageviews for every bitmap of list to FrameLayout.

It will surely work. I have used this method to generate animation of image and succeeded.
I am saving all bitmaps as png in internal storage for later use.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ftf2t.gif) is what i have done. I added every image after interval of 1 second because i need to animate it for my app. You can put every image without interval.

Comment: Everything is working good with the code what i have but the only issue is from the second path onwards the path ending point is added to the begining point of first path.

Comment: @RajiRaji that's what i am trying to tell you. after drawing one path, you need to add that cropped bitmap to list and refresh your canvas,clear path and repeat.